# Expected end of line but found identifier

Tags: applescript

So I was doing some coding duh and I made this
umm I didn't paste it because it was bugging out but yea the important part is this little thing

display dialog "Cya D: You should have played" buttons "Ok"

I know it seems super simple but it dosent work it says Expected end of line but found identifier. its so annoying and just saying it highlights Cya please help

Comment: This line is correct and compiles. The error lies somewhere else.

Comment: Yea I'm pulling out my hair I will just restart .-.

Comment: Could be invalid double quotes caused by pasted code. Check that.

Answer (score 3):

AppleScript 2 no longer includes the Scripting Additions (which includes basic stuff like display dialog) if you have a use statement. You have to add:

```
use scripting additions
```

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-SW5

Comment: The `display dialog` _command_ is a part of **StandardAdditions** and does not require the use of `use scripting additions`!

Comment: Apparently if you have a use statement of something else, then you do need `use scripting additions`. I added a `use application "x"`, and it broke display dialog for the rest of my script

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{"OK"}
```

instead of

```
"OK"
```

buttons is usually followed by a list.